# How to update fill_between?

Tags: python, matplotlib

In `matplotlib`, the data of `plot` can be updated by using `set_xdata` and `set_ydata`:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

line, = plt.plot([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
line.set_ydata([6, 5, 4])
plt.show()
```

How is the data of `fill_between` updated? The closest method I could find is `set_offsets`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fill = plt.fill_between([1, 2, 3], [5, 5, 5], [4, 5, 6])
fill.set_offsets([[3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 6]])
plt.show()
```

I tried to change `y1` from `[5, 5, 5]` to `[3, 4, 5]` in the above code, but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to change the vertices of a [`PolyCollection`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection) using the [`.set_verts()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection.set_verts) method.

From your original `fill` object, you can extract the current vertices from the `Path` object returned from [`.get_paths()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection.get_paths):

```py
verts = fill.get_paths()[0].vertices
```

If you print that out, you can see which values we need to change:

```py
array([[1., 4.],
       [1., 5.],
       [2., 5.],
       [3., 5.],
       [3., 6.],
       [3., 6.],
       [2., 5.],
       [1., 4.],
       [1., 4.]])
```

So let's modify those 5's to `6,5,4` as requested:

```py
verts[1:4, 1] = [6, 5, 4]
```

And then we need to update the original `PolyCollection` with our new vertices:

```py
fill.set_verts([verts])
```

Putting this all together in a script:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fill = plt.fill_between([1, 2, 3], [5, 5, 5], [4, 5, 6])

plt.savefig('original.png')

verts = fill.get_paths()[0].vertices
verts[1:4, 1] = [6, 5, 4]
fill.set_verts([verts])

plt.savefig('updated.png')
```

Gives these two figures:

original.png:
[image: original.png]

updated.png:
[image: updated.png]

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to change `fill_between()`, it would need to be `remove()` the original polycollection (Refer [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between.html)) and then do it again. Hope this is what you are looking for...

```
x=[1, 2, 3]
y=[4, 5, 6]
y1=[6, 5, 4]
line,= plt.plot(x,y, c='k')
fill=plt.fill_between(x,y)
## If you comment below lines, you will get the original line and fill between

line.set_ydata(y1) ## Change the line
fill.remove()  ##Remove the fill_between
plt.fill_between(x,y1) ## .... and create new one
plt.show()
```

Plot with just the first lines...

[image]

Plot after removing and adding new one...

[image]